# Type Qualifier Syntax and Static Const Method Incompatibility

Tags: c++, static, constants, static-methods

**Question #1: Asymmetry between type specifiers and qualifiers**

In C++ type specifiers are used in both declarations and definitions.  For example, if I declare

```
unsigned int numWheels();
```

in a Car class, then I define the function using the same type specifier:

```
unsigned int Car::numWheels()
```

Type qualifiers are different.  When I declare:

```
static unsigned int numWheels();
```

the correct way to define is without the static qualifier:

```
unsigned int Car::numWheels()
```

Is there a reason why type qualifiers are used in declarations but not definitions (other than "just because").

**Second question: Why are static methods incompatible with const?**

In general, the best approach for global variables (I'm sure there are counter examples, I'm speaking generally) is to implement the global variable as a protected static class variable, and then create public getters and/or setters.  The most obvious way of doing this would be:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static int getReadOnlyInt() const;

protected:
    static int readOnlyInt_;
};

int Foo::readOnlyInt_ = 0;

int Foo::getReadOnlyInt() const
{
    return readOnlyInt_;
}
```

but this is wrong. In creating class Foo, I wanted to indicate to future users of Foo that the method Foo::getReadOnlyInt() is guaranteed to be an inspector, not a mutator.   The variable readOnlyInt_ is safe from tinkering!  Hence, declared with the cv-qualifier const.

However, the compiler tells me that cv qualifiers are forbidden on static methods.  Even a method that should be declared with const, like a getter.

Seems like an odd design decision for the language.  Why are cv-qualifiers verboten on static methods?

Comment: `static` is not a type-qualifier (no such term exists), it is a storage-class-specifier. It is incorrect to say that static "is used in declarations but not definitions". `static` is an overloaded keyword and can mean different things depending on context. In some cases `static` can be used in a definition, in others it cannot. Other storage-class-specifiers have different rules.

Comment: Static methods are incompatible with `const` because `const` in the method signature qualifies `this` pointer. Static methods don't have `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why type qualifiers are used in declarations but not definitions (other than "just because").

`static` is not a type qualifier.

If the question is re-writen to be "why is `static` keyword used in declarations but not in definitions", the answer would be that `static` has different meanings inside and outside a class. The so-called "symmetry" would cause confusion if not ambiguity.

> Second question: Why are static methods incompatible with const?

Static member function does not have `this` pointer. There is nothing to const-qualify.